# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Permission denied Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Permission denied in Firebase Chat. Tried this but not working. I have tried in Realtime database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true",
  }
}
```

Loot at screenshot for detailed error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/118Zi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this with following code

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 9963441200000",  // 2022-9-18
    ".write": "now < 9963441200000",  // 2022-9-18
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean values don't require quotation marks.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}
```

In your own answer you used an expression that is evaluated, which does need the quotation marks. Writing `"now < 9963441200000"` is exactly the same as `true`, since `now` is a Unix Timestap which caps at 2147483647000 and will always be less than that value.

Note that neither is a secure set of rules.

The [Realtime Database Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) section of the documentation goes into more detail.